# Pushforward of structure sheaf of a curve under a finite map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow C$ be a double cover of smooth projective curves. We know that $f_*O_X$ is a rank two vector bundle and it splits as a direct sum of line bundles $O_C\oplus L$. Is it possible that $L=O_C$ as well. That is, can the push forward of structure sheaf be trivial?

Comment: Assuming both the curves are irreducible, no. Since $k=H^0(\mathcal{O}_X)=H^0(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ and if the the pushforward is direct sum of two copies of $\mathcal{O}_C$, it will have two dimensional global sections. Also, your claim that the direct image splits holds in general only for characteristic not 2.

Comment: @Mohan, irreducibility of $X$ is not clear. So I was wondering if one can construct a double cover with $f_*O_X=O_C\oplus O_C$. I can take $X$ to be disjoint union of two copies of $C$. Is this the only possible $X$?

Comment: If you assume both are smooth curves, disjoint union is the only possibility.